# Quiero saber como manipular de vuelta el array de json para poder sacar cada dato

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

Muy buenas.

Quisiera saber por que en la base  me ingresa en el campo la información de esta forma:

```
["producto","cero","etc","etc"]
```

Sin embargo yo quisera que lo pusiera asi como en json

```
"","","",""
```

De hecho aqui lo está poniendo como en json pero agrega los `[]` eso es lo que quiero quitar por que despues lo que quiero es decodificar del json guardado y mediante `fetch(PDO::fetchobj)` sacar con un `foreach` cada string.

Lo que yo codifico a json es un array pasado desde html con unos campos para meter en un solo string el array y optimizar campos.

Aquí está el código PHP:

```
   public function upLoadFormulas($titulo,$descripcionbreve,$rutaimg,$arrayproductosquimicos,$arrayporcentajesqumicos,$tipocomp,$descripcion,$arrayurlvideos){
   $arrayquimicos = json_encode($arrayproductosquimicos);
   $arrayporcentajes = json_encode($arrayporcentajesqumicos);
   $arravideosurls = json_encode($arrayurlvideos);
   $date =  date("m.d.y");
   $id = 1;
   try{
            $db = getDB();// hace la conexion a la base de datos

//        tenemos que insertar en la base de datos el id de la sesion del admin al ingrsar el ultimo valor que es la clave foranea    

        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO formulas (titulo_formulas,des_breve_fomula,ruta_imagen,qumicos_formula,porcentajes_formula,tipo_compo_formula,des_entera_formula,url_videos_formula,fecha_formula,Aid) VALUES  (:titulo,:descripcionbreve,:rutaimg,:arrayquimicos,:arrayporcentajes,:tipocomp,:descripcion,:urlvideos,:fechaformula,:Aid)"); //  insertamos todos los valores del formulario de las formulas
        // hacer todos los param para insertar en la base de datos uun por cada campo 
        $stmt->bindParam("titulo", $titulo,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
        $stmt->bindParam("descripcionbreve", $descripcionbreve,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
        $stmt->bindParam("rutaimg", $rutaimg,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
        $stmt->bindParam("arrayquimicos", $arrayquimicos) ;
        $stmt->bindParam("arrayporcentajes", $arrayporcentajes,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
        $stmt->bindParam("tipocomp", $tipocomp,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
        $stmt->bindParam("descripcion", $descripcion,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
        $stmt->bindParam("urlvideos", $arravideosurls,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
        $stmt->bindParam("fechaformula",$date,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
        $stmt->bindParam("Aid", $id,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
```

[image: este es el ejemplo en la base de datos]

esto lo hago por que despues quiero recuperar esa fila y hacer un for each al array del objeto y separarlo en tanto como haya

Comment: No entiendo muy bien el lío que te traes con los datos, por qué los manipulas tanto, por qué guardas esos datos de esa forma en la BD y no de una forma organizada y separada. No se entiende cómo son los datos en el origen o por qué los conviertes, los desconviertes para luego querer volver a convertirlos. Si tratas de explicar mejor el contexto de tu aplicación entonces quizá podríamos ayudarte mejor. De hecho tuve que editar la pregunta para darle un poco más de claridad porque como estaba redactada era imposible siquiera imaginar cuál era el problema.

Comment: No quieres guardar JSON pero los estas codificando a JSON? no entiendo esa parte

Comment: Lo que quiero es sacar ese Json codificado y sacar el array mediante un for racha ya me di cuenta de que lo guarda en json pero tengo problemas en como extraerlo

Comment: @A.Cedano  yo lo que quiero es lo ya guardado en json en cadena quiero retornarlo de base de datos y poder manipular en php mediante un array y sacar cada cadena por separado

Comment: Guillermo podrías por favor explicar brevemente cada cosa, **paso a paso** qué es lo que haces y qué es lo que quieres. Es que tienes un lío entre si JSON, array, JSON, array, JSON ... que no se entiende. Olvídate del JSON y del array y dinos punto por punto: 1. lo que tienes; 2. lo que estás haciendo; 3. lo que estás obteniendo; 4. lo que quieres obtener. Gracias.

Comment: @A.Cedano 1 lo que  primero hago es obtener de un formulario todos los datos  3 de los datos están en array mediante el campo nombre  array químicos array porcentajes y array url vídeos  después lo proceso con php para meterlo en la base de datos los 3 arrays les hago un json_encode y los meto en la base de datos y despues en una función lo que quiero hacer es convertir ese json otra vez en área y y poder manipularlo con un for each para poder escribir cada palabra por separado

Comment: Donde digo en área quise decir en array